# Batch Script: Move files to folder based on source folder name

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have read a couple of questions with a similar theme but none seem to cover this scenario.

I am looking to use a batch file that will check whether a directory is empty and if it contains files, move them to a corresponding folder.  From here it will then check a second directory and do the same but to a different corresponding folder.

For Example:

Checks whether C:\One contains files, if it does move all the contents to C:\Receive\One

At this point (or if C:\One is empty) it will move and check whether C:\Two contains files.  If it does it will move all files to C:\Receive\Two and stop the script. If C:\Two is empty the script will also stop here.

At present I'm using two scripts so was just interested as to whether there was a way to do it tidier with one script.

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "c:\one\*.*"') do ( 
    move C:\One\* C:\Receive\One 
    goto :EOF 
)
echo No Files To Move
```

Comment: We do not write code for you.  ***Show your own work***, then explain what problems you have encountered.

Comment: @TomBagley `goto :eof` seems to be quite useless at that position. Please check the code (may have suffered from editing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like a simple move, in two lines:

```
move C:\One\*.* C:\Receive\One\
move C:\Two\*.* C:\Receive\Two\
```

Or, if you really need to do it in a batch-loop:

```
for %%a in (One Two) do (
    move C:\%%a\*.* C:\Receive\%%a\
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo No files to move from %%a
)
```

Comment: Only a simple move when you know how! Thank you that's really helped my understanding.